# Why do I have a page hit for 404.php after each legitimate pagehit?

Tags: php, apache2, http-status-code-404

I'm working with an intranet system that, on each page, checks the user's cookie, verifies that they can see the current page based on database permissions, and records a page hit that includes their id and the page URL.

I just noticed that in the pagehits table, I see an entry for 404.php (my custom 404 page specified in the Apache config) one second after each legitimate page hit.

**Is this probably my fault, or does it have something to do with how Apache decides to load the 404 page?**

I'm using Apache 2.2.14 (Win32) and PHP 5.3.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess would be that you have no favicon.ico defined for your site.

That means that every time a user requests a page, the browser is also requesting favicon.ico which results in a 404 being returned.

Answer (score 5):

You probably have a request for a file which doesn't exist. Maybe your favicon. The Apache error or access logs will reveal what the 404 was for.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading your logs and see which url trigger the 404 response code. Also you can install some log analyzer like awstats